# Setup Email Receiving AWS SES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

How can i setup email receiving
I have nodejs server I want to build endpoint for fetching all emails

My Options are:
Option1: 
save all incoming email to mongodb then I'll fetch it on Mongodb
Possible Problems:How? I have local server for now.

Option2:
Save email on aws (if Possibe) then fetch it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing for you to do will to setup aws ses to save incoming emails to a designated s3 bucket. Once it is in the bucket you can do what you want with it, or even better, set up an s3 event notification that triggers another call (a lambda function for example), each time the email is put in the bucket for you to do your downstream processing of it.

> As part of the AWS infrastructure, Amazon SES can also take action on
>   your mail, such as delivering it to an Amazon S3 bucket, publishing it
>   to an Amazon SNS topic, calling your custom code through AWS Lambda,
>   integrating with Amazon WorkMail, or bouncing the mail back to the
>   sender.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html

Comment: Can i setup lambda functions without s3?